# Method parameters with type like { def foo() }

Tags: scala

While scanning through `dispatch` code base, I noticed a method is defined like this:

```
def pack[T](req: { def abort() }, result: => T): HttpPackage[T]
```

The type annotation `{ def abort() }` looks very strange to me. I thought it might be some thing similar to duck typing, so I tried to pass with some thing like `object bar { def foo = print("Hello, world!") }` but the compiler still complain type mismatched. I googled but couldn't find any article mention about it.

Does anyone know about this type annotation and its use cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [structural typing](https://dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural) in the Scala world, or more colloquially, as *duck typing*. From the linked article:

```
def quacker(duck: {def quack(value: String): String}) {
  println (duck.quack("Quack"))
}

object BigDuck {
  def quack(value: String) = {
    value.toUpperCase
  }
}

quacker(BigDuck)
```

so your method above will accept *any* object that defines an `abort()` method, without implementing a specific interface/trait.

This is particularly useful for handling sets of classes that implement the same methods without a common interface/trait, and that you can't retrofit an interface over (e.g. from legacy apps/libraries)

Answer (score 2):

This defines a parameter `req` with a structural type i.e. a type defined by the existence of certain members. In this case any type with an `abort()` method. You can't pass `bar` since it does not have such a method. If you defined it as:

```
object Bar {
   def abort(): Unit = print("Aborting!")
}
```

then you can pass it to `pack`:

```
pack(Bar, { ... })
```